# SQL Azure only returning one row in sys.dm_exec_sessions

Tags: sql-server, azure

In on-premises Microsoft SQL Server, when I issue this query:

SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions

I get one record per window in SSMS.  If I open several query windows in SSMS, I get a record for each of those, even if they're not doing anything.  In Azure, when I issue that same query, I only get one record back.  Here's the kicker - I even only get one record back when I've got multiple windows in SSMS doing active work in Azure.

Here's a screenshot:

[SQL Azure http://s3temp.brentozar.com/azure1.png](http://s3temp.brentozar.com/azure1.png)

In that screenshot, I've got three active tabs in SSMS.  Two of them are running giant insert statements that take several seconds to execute, and the third one is querying sys.dm_exec_sessions - but I'm only getting one record back.  I get multiple records in sys.dm_tran_active_transactions and sys.dm_tran_database_transactions, but this changes how I report on active queries if I can't tie it back to individual sessions.  Is that expected behavior, or something MS is working to fix in Azure vNext?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After escalating this inside Microsoft, they've agreed that there's a bug in sys.dm_exec_sessions.  It's improperly filtered, so it always shows just your current session and no other sessions regardless of your permissions.  They'll update it in a future release of SQL Azure.

More info in the MSDN thread if you need proof:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdsgetstarted/thread/db88c830-0b0a-4e38-ad93-062d12d55c31

Answer (score 9):

The behavior of Azure is the same as SQL:

> Permissions: Requires VIEW SERVER STATE permission
>   on server.
>
> Note:   If the user has VIEW SERVER
>   STATE permission on the server, the
>   user will see all executing sessions
>   on the instance of SQL Server;
>   otherwise, **the user will see only the
>   current session**.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's a catch here.  You can grant someone VIEW DATABASE STATE, but you can't grant them VIEW SERVER STATE in Azure.  VIEW DATABASE STATE doesn't show you multiple connections either. Dang.

Comment: I don't have an Azure account (or I do? can't remember) but can you check that sys.dm_exec_sessions has the same definition: `CREATE VIEW sys.dm_exec_sessions AS SELECT * FROM OpenRowset(TABLE SYSSESSIONS)`, no additional WHERE added in Azure?

Comment: The Azure team has verified that there's a bug in sys.dm_exec_sessions.  It only shows the current session.  They'll fix it in a future update.